# How can I bind event for html markup variable using jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, events, bind, markup

Suppose I have a variable which store html markup:

```
var $content=$("<div id='test'></div>")
```

then I want give it a click event,and append it to body element

```
$content.click(function(){
    console.log('click!');
});

$content.appendTo($('body'))
```

however it doesn't work ,how can I make it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `click` handler gets set up just fine. The problem is that with a completely empty div, it has a height of `0` (unless you've done styling somewhere that you haven't shown), and so you can't find it to click on it. [Zero-height example](http://jsbin.com/imumaz) | [source](http://jsbin.com/imumaz/edit).

The solution is to put content in the div, or to give it styling to give it height:

[Content example](http://jsbin.com/imumaz/2) | [source](http://jsbin.com/imumaz/2/edit):

```
var $content=$("<div id='test'>I'm the div!</div>");
$content.click(function(){
    console.log('click!');
});
$content.appendTo($('body'));
```

[Styling example](http://jsbin.com/imumaz/3) | [source](http://jsbin.com/imumaz/3/edit):

JavaScript:

```
var $content=$("<div id='test'></div>");
$content.click(function(){
    console.log('click!');
});
$content.appendTo($('body'));
```

CSS:

```
#test {
    height: 20px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

---

Side note:

> Suppose I have a variable which store html markup:
>
> `var $content=$("<div id='test'></div>");`

Note that you're not storing HTML markup. By calling jQuery with HTML markup, you're telling jQuery to create the relevant DOM elements and wrap them in a jQuery instance.

To store *markup* in a variable, you'd just store the string containing the markup:

```
var content="<div id='test'></div>";
```

Markup is text; elements are objects.

---

**Update**: Re your comment below:

> I write this code in jquery plugin js file...does it have some matter?

It matters if your code is running before there's a `body` element to append to; your last line will fail without a `body` element (for instance, if you code is running immediately on load, and it's loaded from the `head` element). If the `body` element exists as of when you run your code, it should be fine.

Comment: no,I think if I set a height to it,it also doesn't work.In my real case,it's a option tag

Comment: @hh54188: If you set a height, it does work. See the examples I added.

Comment: @T:alright...I write this code in jquery plugin js file...does it have some matter?

Comment: @hh54188: Not unless your code is running before the `body` element exists. See update. If you quote the relevant code, do a proper failing test case, it's a lot easier to help you.